# PHP: Browser go back a page

Tags: php, javascript, back

I want for something like this:

```
<?php
if($something)
    header('Location:javascript:history.go(-2)');
?>
```

but `header('Location:javascript:history.go(-2)');` doesn't work. Any alternatives?

I don't know the page the user was just on, so I can't hardcode the url.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your point of view, i think you might be looking for something like this:

```
<html><head></head><body>
<?php
if($something){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.history.go(-2);
</script>
<?php
}
?>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Too bad I get the "send post data again?" browser prompt again

Comment: No problem, I imagine the prompt could be circumvented by a combination of AJAX in your pages. For example, the browser history points to a GET Request which for the ease of the example has something ending on #page-bla&postvars. You could then on loading of the page scan for window.location.hashname which then should contain #page-bla&postvars. If you know "postvars" is present in the string you could post your ajax query and also do something with the result. This way you would have no prompt.

Answer (score 3):

As long as they got there by a link you could use

```
header("Location: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

Comment: Might want to wrap it with `isset()` and ensure it is not an empty string.

Comment: Hmm, I think for that kind of thing you would be better off just sending an empty page with a javascript in it. Something like in dizas's answer

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the `javascript:` pseudo protocol in a `Location` HTTP header. In fact, you really shouldn't be using it at all.

Instead, send the whole URL to the page you want the user to go back to via the `Location` HTTP header (if you can)  *or* you could echo the `history.back()` though I **highly discourage that you do**.

As a side note, always `exit` after sending the `Location` HTTP header. User agents don't have to follow it.

Answer (score 0):

According to your problem .you can use following code in php script at any where..

code:

```
  <?php

     if($something){
       echo "<script>window.history.back()</script>";
      } 
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($something) print '<script>window.history.go(-2);</script>';
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, 
**[including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) 
really helps to improve the quality of your post**. Remember that you are 
answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might 
not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd 
your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both 
the code and the explanations!