# Go Back A Few Pages After Form Submission

Tags: javascript, php

Desired flow

1. link 1 : `www.example.com` (list of all persons)
2. press view button on person 1
3. link 2 : `www.example.com?view-person=1` (view details of person 1)
4. press edit button
5. link 3: `www.example.com?edit-person=1` (editing form for person1)
6. press submit then return to `?view-person=1`

Form action in `?edit-person` is `action="www.example.com"`.

Inside `www.example.com` is the following snippet

```
if(isset($_POST['edit-person']))
{
// record edit
header("location:javascript://history.go(-1)"); // supposed to go back to ?view-person but just returns to ?edit-person
}
```

I've tried

`header("location:javascript://history.go(-1)");`

And

`header("location:javascript://history.go(-2)");`

But it just sends me back to `?edit-person=1` instead of `?view-person=1`.

I can't also just do `header("location:www.example.com?view-person='$id'");` because it sends me to `www.example.com?view-person=%272%27`

I dont know if what I'm planning is possible or not.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7466286/102441

Comment: _" I can't also just do..."_ why not?

Comment: This is going back a page after a submission. I know how to go back a page if there is no submission done.

Comment: Now try it without the single quotes, like in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do `javascript:` urls even work in the `Location` header? You're not doing PHP string interpolation correctly - you want:

```
header("location:www.example.com?view-person=$id");
```

Comment: I now remember. I once tried to echo the value of the query dynamically inside an href anchor. `<a href="www.example.com?random=<?php echo $id; ?>">` but it didn't work. I'll try to find that problem again and see to it.

Answer (score 1):

You're using GET Method and validating by POST, use $_REQUEST instead.

i've tried this code and it works fine.

```
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['edit-person']))
{
  echo "<script>history.go(-2);</script>";
}
?>
```